# MYSQL multiple updates

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I want to update the same column of a table, for different cases in one shot. What is the best way I can achieve this? For example, I want to achieve the same thing as the below statements in one SQL query :

```
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'BALLET' WHERE LOGIN = 'arachel';
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'EXOTIC_BELLY_DANCER' WHERE LOGIN = 'mandanah';
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'JAZZ' WHERE LOGIN = 'kbianca';
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'FUSION' WHERE LOGIN = 'lmorgan';
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'BOLLYWOOD' WHERE LOGIN = 'idcruz';
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = 'SAMBA' WHERE LOGIN = 'pcastillo';
```

What is the best way to update the DANCER_TYPE column, using a single query, in the most scaleable and efficient manner?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? The very reason you need it to be just one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE
   SET TYPE = CASE LOGIN 
                      WHEN 'arachel' THEN 'BALLET' 
                      WHEN 'mandanah' THEN 'EXOTIX_BELLY_DANCER' 
                      ELSE 'YOURELSEVALUE'
                   END;
```

should work for your case (only did 2 examples)

Comment: if you don't want to do anything on else, just use: ELSE NULL

Comment: Without a `WHERE`, this will scan the entire table _and_ change every row!

Comment: @RickJames isn't that what OP wants: to automaticly assign the type for each dancer

Answer (score 2):

Use CASE - EXPRESSION

```
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE 
SET TYPE = CASE WHEN LOGIN = 'arachel' THEN 'BALLET'  
                WHEN LOGIN = 'mandanah' THEN 'EXOTIC_BELLY_DANCER' 
                WHEN LOGIN = 'kbianca' THEN 'JAZZ' 
                WHEN LOGIN = 'lmorgan' THEN 'FUSION'  
                WHEN LOGIN = 'idcruz' THEN 'BOLLYWOOD' 
                WHEN LOGIN = 'pcastillo' THEN 'SAMBA'            
            END
 WHERE LOGIN IN ('arachel', 'mandanah','kbianca','lmorgan','idcruz''pcastillo');
```

Comment: Depending on data, it could be an idea to add `where LOGIN IN ('arachel', ...)` to keep transaction size down.

Comment: Yes That`s make sens -That`s why already place ELSE part that will set same value if above condition are not true

Comment: I don't know how Oracle treats a column value updated to the same value as before. Is it included in write sets etc?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone here gave an answer based on the 'one query' request. They are all right. you need to use a `case` statement AND the `where` condition.

For the 'efficient manner' part of your question, you have to add an `INDEX` on the `login` field if you don't have it already.

So, it would be:

```
create index IDX_DANCER_TYPE_LOGIN on DANCER_TYPE(login);
```

And use the answer from @SamiKuhmonen

```
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = CASE login
                                WHEN 'arachel' THEN 'BALLET'
                                WHEN 'mandanah' THEN 'EXOTIC_BELLY_DANCER'
                                ...
                                END
                 WHERE login IN ('arachel', 'mandanah', ...);
```

Plus his explanation on the `else`

IN MY OPINION there is no `more scaleable way` then run the updates separated with the index created.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "best", "most scalable" and "most efficient" can have very different meanings. You'll have to define them first. Superlatives don't work well.

But if you want a single query you can use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE DANCER_TYPE SET TYPE = CASE login
  WHEN 'arachel' THEN 'BALLET'
  WHEN 'mandanah' THEN 'EXOTIC_BELLY_DANCER'
  ...
  END
  WHERE login IN ('arachel', 'mandanah', ...);
```

The `WHERE` condition to make sure you don't update unnecessary fields. Depending on RDBMS implementation you might get away with just `ELSE type` and no `WHERE` condition.

Comment: i like the WHERE condition there, didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using InnoDB, doing the `UPDATEs` in a single transaction will help due to xaction overhead:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...
UPDATE ...
...
COMMIT;
```

*Probably* the use of `CASE` and `WHERE` mentioned in other answers is faster than this.